# Python find tilde in string

Tags: python, string, find

I'm trying to find "~" in a string, but it returns 0.

Can someone help here?

```
tt = "~"
tt.find("~")
Out[393]: 0
```

Answer (score 3):

with `find` you are looking for the position of the substring in the string. `0` means that your substring starts at index `0`.
If you want to check only if the string contains a substring, you can use:

`~` at the beginning of the string:

```
my_string = "~ This is a test"
print("~" in my_string) # True
print(my_string.find("~")) # 0 (index)
```

this means that `~` can be found at index 0 in your string. Since python starts to count indexes from 0, means that `~` is the first character (which is true!)

`~` in the middle of the string:

```
my_string = "This is a ~ test"
print("~" in my_string) # True
print(my_string.find("~")) # 10 (index)
```

this means that `~` can be found at index 10 in your string. this means that `~` is the 11th character (which is true!)

`~` not in the string:

```
my_string = "This is a test"
print("~" in my_string) # False
print(my_string.find("~")) # -1 (false)
```

Two `~` in the string:

```
my_string = "~This is a ~test"
print("~" in my_string) # True
print(my_string.find("~")) # 0 (only the index of the FIRST ~!)
```

There are [many operations](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) you can perform on string.

Answer (score 1):

`0` means "found at position 0".

`-1` means "not found".

All is well.

Answer (score 1):

The function is working alright.
Python's indexing works from 0 (not 1). The output of 0 means it found '~' at 0th index. If `find` does not find a character, it outputs -1.

Answer (score 0):

The class `str` has method `find` which looks for an occurence of a substring within the string. It returns the position of the found substring. If the substring could not be found, then it returns `-1`.

In your example `tt = "~"`, the tilde symbol is at position 0. When you run the command `tt.find("~")`, the tilde is found at position 0 and that value is returned.

Check this example for better understanding:

```
tt = "The tilde ~ symbol"
tt.find("~")
# 10
```

The method `find` accepts one positional argument (the substring to be looked for) and two optional keyword arguments `beg` and `end` - the starting and the ending index respectively.

Imagine this case:

```
tt = "~ where is the ~ symbol ~"
tt.find("~", 1, len(tt)-1)
# 15
```

Here the first and last character are omitted in the search.